# How to utilize matlab to plot a zoomed in map of a region?

Tags: matlab, geoplot

Here is a code I have come across that can plot the map of a country in latitude-longitude coordinate system using matlab:

```
GT = readgeotable("landareas.shp");
australia = GT(GT.Name == "Australia",:);
shape = australia.Shape;

cities = readgeotable("worldcities.shp");
querypoint = cities.Shape;

inpoly = isinterior(shape,querypoint);
citiesAU = cities(inpoly,:);

figure
geoplot(shape)
hold on
geoplot(citiesAU,"mo",MarkerFaceColor="m")
```

If you run this, you will see that it will draw the entire map of Australia. However, what I want is to draw a zoomed-in version of the map that is constrained in a window *[130E, 140E]* and *[20S, 30S]* including all major and minor cities as small dots with a size depending on their population as well as all rivers, national parks and important landmarks.

Thank you for your help,